# have a list of months need to select latest for each person

Tags: r, date

I have data in the below format

```
   name  date          x  y  z 
    a    March-2018    1  2  2
    a    Feb-2018      2  3  3
    b    June-2017     3  4  4
    b    April-2017    4  5  5
    c    Sep-2018      5  5  6
    c    Aug-2017      7  7  8
```

Need to select the name and other columns based on latest Month as below.

```
   name  date          x  y  z 
    a    March-2018    1  2  2
    b    June-2017     3  4  4
    c    Sep-2018      5  5  6
```

I tried with distinct names and selecting max date but didn't workout.

Comment: Can you do a ls.str(your.dataframe) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the `date` column to an actual date column by pasting an arbitrary date ("01") and then `group_by` `name` and get the `max` row.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(newdate = as.Date(paste0("01-", date), "%d-%b-%Y")) %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   slice(which.max(newdate)) %>%
   select(-newdate)

 #   name     date           x     y     z
 #  <fct>     <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
 #1   a     March-2018     1     2     2
 #2   b     June-2017      3     4     4
 #3   c     Sep-2018       5     5     6
```

---

A base R option using `ave`, we first convert the dates and then get `max` dates by group (`name`) and subset it from original dataframe.

```
df$new_date <- as.Date(paste0("01-", df$date), "%d-%b-%Y")
#I was trying to use which.max instead of max but it giving me an error, not sure why
df[with(df, new_date %in% ave(new_date, name, FUN = max)), ]

# name       date x y z   new_date
#1    a March-2018 1 2 2 2018-03-01
#3    b  June-2017 3 4 4 2017-06-01
#5    c   Sep-2018 5 5 6 2018-09-01
```

Note - As mentioned by @ IceCreamToucan  `ave` method works here because each `name` has different `max` `date`, if the date is same it can give different results since we are using `%in%` here.

Comment: Note the `%in% ave(` method assumes no two `name`s share any dates. If the first two rows' dates are June-2017 and July-2017 it returns both rows with `name` equal to `'a'`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan you are right! It can give wrong results if the `max` dates are same. I have updated the answer to add the note. I wonder though why `which.max` doesn't work in `ave` ?

Comment: I think it's because `x` is supposed to be a numeric according to `ave`, so dates are an edge case that isn't oficially supported. If you use `as.numeric(new_date)` as your `x` then `which.max` works as a `FUN`

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(temp = match(gsub("-.*$", "", date), month.abb), 
        temp2 = ifelse(is.na(temp), match(gsub("-.*$", "", date), month.name), temp)) %>%
 group_by(name) %>%
 filter(temp2 == max(temp2)) %>%
 select(-starts_with("temp"))
  name  date           x     y     z
  <fct> <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
1 a     March-2018     1     2     2
2 b     June-2017      3     4     4
3 c     Sep-2018       5     5     6
```

First, it takes out the names of months from "date" and then assign a number to abbreviated months names, with January being 1 and December being 12. Second, it assigns a number to non-abbreviated months names. Third, it filters out the rows per group with the highest number assigned to months. Finally, it removes the redundant variables.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a roundabout way of replicating `group_by` and `slice` in base using `split` and `lapply` with `[`.

```
do.call(rbind, 
lapply(split(df, df$name), 
       function(x) x[which.max(as.Date(paste0("01-", x$date), "%d-%b-%Y")),])
)
#   name       date x y z
# a    a March-2018 1 2 2
# b    b  June-2017 3 4 4
# c    c   Sep-2018 5 5 6
```

Another option is to `aggregate` and then `merge`. Seems like there may be some other sinple way to do this in base I'm missing.

```
to.keep <- 
  aggregate(date ~ name, data = df, 
            function(x) x[which.max(as.Date(paste0("01-", x), "%d-%b-%Y"))])

merge(df, to.keep, by = names(to.keep))

#   name       date x y z
# a    a March-2018 1 2 2
# b    b  June-2017 3 4 4
# c    c   Sep-2018 5 5 6
```

Data used

```
structure(list(name = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), date = c("March-2018", 
"Feb-2018", "June-2017", "April-2017", "Sep-2018", "Aug-2017"
), x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L), y = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L
), z = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```